# Extracting the 1st non-zero digit from a numeric in R

Tags: r, extract, numeric

Is there a way you could extract the 1st non-zero digit of a numeric value in R?

Example input:

```
123.01, 0.56, 0.078, 0.0092
```

Output:

```
1, 5, 7, 9
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works with positive inputs:

```
firstdigit <- function(x){ floor(x / 10 ^ floor(log10(x))) }
firstdigit(c(123.01, 0.56, 0.078, 0.0092))
# 1 5 7 9
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm guessing `abs()` would extend this to negative inputs as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sub()` from base R:

```
x <- c("123.01", "0.56", "0.078", "0.0092", "-1.2", "-0.3", "-0.04", "100")

sub("[^1-9]*(.).*", "\\1", x)
```

or with `gsub()`

```
y <- gsub("[^1-9]", "", x)
substr(y, 1,1)
```

This last you can modify to find the second digit:

```
y <- gsub("[^1-9]", "", x)
substr(y, 2,2)
```

---

From the comments:
*For this case the problem needs to be worded differently.

"Extract the second digit after leading zeros" or "extract the second significant figure".*

```
y <- sub("^[^1-9]*", "", x)
y <- gsub("\\.", "", y)
substr(y, 2,2)
```

Comment: Thank you! However, the second digit version does not work if the second digit is a 0 (i.e. 100)

Comment: What should be the result, if there is no second non-zero digit?

Comment: For this case the problem needs to be worded differently. "Extract the second digit after leading zeros" or "extract the second significant figure".

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to extract. Using the `stringr` package:

```r
set.seed(1)
x <- c(123.01, 0.56, 0.078, 0.0092)
x
#> [1] 123.0100   0.5600   0.0780   0.0092

stringr::str_extract(as.character(x), "([1-9]{1})")
#> [1] "1" "5" "7" "9"
```

You can convert back to numeric as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `gsub` to remove leading 0's, `trimws` to remove dot and 0 or more zeroes and then extract first character using `substr`.

```
x <- c(123.01, 0.56, 0.078, 0.0092)
substr(trimws(gsub('^0', '', x), "left", "\\.0*"), 1, 1)
#[1] "1" "5" "7" "9"
```

Comment: This will be very useful for me since I can easily extend this to the second digit case, which I will later need in my analysis. Thank you!